# Can I post both checked and unchecked box values on same script

Tags: php, jquery

I want to get both checked and unchecked box values on same script. The method I have used on my script is not working get me over this. I want to get multiple checkbox values without using submit button. Is it possible to get both statuses of checkbox values?

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var ids = [];
  var dis = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).val());
  });
  $('input[type=checkbox]:unchecked').each(function() {
    dis.push($(this).val());

  });
  //var allCheckboxes=$(".#form1").find(".check_list")
  //var unchecked=allCheckboxes.not(":checked");
  dis = dis.toString();
  ids = ids.toString();
  $.ajax({
    url: "dummyeodcheckbox.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: ({
      value: ids,
      unchecked: dis
    }),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("activitysubmitted");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="form1">
  <div align="center" id="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>S.NO</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Check Box</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Activity Name</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="checklist[]" value="Bod1" id="b1" <?php echo $status ?> />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="Bod1">BOD1 </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="checklist[]" value="Bod2" id="b2" <?php echo $status ?> />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="Bod2">BOD2 </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="checklist[]" value="Bod3" id="b3" <?php echo $status ?> />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="Bod3">BOD3</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="checklist[]" value="Bod4" id="b4" <?php echo $status ?> />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="Bod4">BOD4 </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there is no `:unchecked` selector in jQuery. Instead you can use `:not(:checked)`, like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function() {
  dis.push($(this).val());
});
```

I'd also suggest you use `map()` to make the array building more succinct, and also `join()` the arrays instead of using `toString()`.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var ids = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  var dis = $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get()

  $.ajax({
    url: "dummyeodcheckbox.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: ({
      value: ids,
      unchecked: dis,
    }),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("activitysubmitted");
    }
  });
});
```

You should also consider returning XML or JSON from the AJAX request. `text` can be easily broken by whitespace inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input `type="hidden"` to store value of checkboxes.